# Can't use imported image component in innerHTML in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to dynamically show an image(imported as component) inside a div.
My code looks like :

```
import prevIcon from './images/prev_icon.svg';

let newNode = document.createElement('div');
newNode.innerHTML = '<img src=' + { prevIcon } + ' width="30px" height="30px" />';
```

Unfortunately,this doesn't work.The **prevIcon** doesn't come up as an image.

On inspecting the rendered html,I get somthing like following:

```
<img src="[object" object]="" width="30px" height="30px">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, you miss quotes between `src`

```
import prevIcon from './images/prev_icon.svg';

let newNode = document.createElement('div');
newNode.innerHTML = '<img src="' + prevIcon + '" width="30px" height="30px" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you import images you need to set up `file-loader` in your webpack configuration object.

Here is it: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader

Here is exemple configuration:

```
{
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|ico)$/i,
    loader: 'file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]',
  },
```